# Only custom events are getting logged twice with serilog

Tags: azure, azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.1, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I have a custom logger which implements serilog. Trace are getting logged once but the events are getting logged twice.

Below is the host.json:

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
            "isEnabled": true,
            "excludedTypes": "Request"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Appsettings:

```
    {
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "abcdef-ghi-49f9-bd20-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

EventLogger is created as below:

```
EventLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
             .Enrich.FromLogContext()
             .WriteTo
             .ApplicationInsights(this.TelemetryConfiguration.InstrumentationKey, TelemetryConverter.Events).CreateLogger();
```

**The problem is just with custom events.Any thoughts on why this can happen?**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "custom events"?

Comment: @mason..custom events are events only..they are logged as custom events in app insight..Check screenshot above